# Push notification in electron

Tags: push-notification, electron

Is there any way to use firebase push notification in electron?I want to create a push notification for my electron app which is a chat app and whenever a new message comes I want to get that notification.But I did not get any good material online to implement it.How can I do it?

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/notifications.md

Answer (score 1):

You can use Websocket.

Python Snippet for websocket

Client Side:

```
from ws4py.client.threadedclient import WebSocketClient
client_url = "ws://server_url + "/websocket/create
ws_client = WebsocketClient(client_url)
ws_client.connect()
```

Server Side: Assuming you have a server with server_url serving the api /websocket/create:

```
from ws4py.websocket import WebSocket

class ws_server(Websocket):
    WebSocket.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

class WebSocketHandler(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def create(self):
        # wsInstance is of type ws_server. Must set userName.
        wsInstance = cherrypy.request.ws_handler
```

And in the Server's config:

```
cherrypy.tree.mount(WebSocketHandler(), '/websocket',
                            config={
                                '/': {
                                    'tools.response_headers.on': True,
                                    'tools.sessions.locking': 'explicit',
                                    'tools.websocket.on': True,
                                    'tools.websocket.handler_cls': ws_server,
                                },
                            })
```